# How to Redirect Domain to Directory .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, web

In a hosting I have two domains that respond to the same address. However, the main one is domain A that owns a website and domain B wants to redirect to a specific directory that has a project of a system on the same server through .htaccess.

Ex: I can access the project through this address below
www.exampleDomainA.com/project

I want the domain below to point to the above directory.
www.exampleDomainB.com

How do I configure this in .htaccess?

When accessing the website load normal
www.exampleDomainA.com/

When accessing www.exampleDomainB.com, load the directory that is in the directory www.exampleDomainA.com/project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine an internal rewriting rule with a condition limiting the application to a specific domain (actually it is a "host name") and one prevent a redirection loop:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.exampleDomainB\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/project/? 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /project/$1 [END]
```

This rule set will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and in case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).